# Fastest way to add a file to git index from windows explorer

Tags: git, windows-10, git-bash, windows-explorer

I'm working on project that involves going to different sub-folders, making changes to files and adding to git index. Right now I have to:

1. Right click inside the folder
2. Open git bash
3. Run the command git add

I tried tortoise git. It shows that the file is modified but does not give any option to 'add to index' from Explorer context menu. This option is present for folders. Is there a faster way (two clicks)?

Comment: `git commit -am "commit message"` is the fastest I feel

Answer (score 1):

Use [StExBar](https://tools.stefankueng.com/StExBar.html) to add the customized command.
Then, you can do this:

[image: Git add]

1. Select the file(s) you want to add
2. Use context menu: `StEx` -> `Git add`

## How to add customized command

[image: StEx - Option]

[image: Add Command]

The command: `git add %selnames`
[image: Add Git Add]

See [StExBar Command options](https://github.com/YueLinHo/tools/wiki/StExBar-Command-options) for available command line optionis

Comment: FWIW I found TortoiseGit to be way more user friendly.

Comment: For a file which is already under version control, TortoiseGit does not support "git add". :)

Comment: Isn't that this? https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-add.html

Comment: not at all. If a file is not under version control by git, the Add item shows up. You can add and commit. After then, if that file is modified, the Add item does not shows up for user. Which means TortoiseGit can not stage file for commit.

Answer (score 0):

You could find git repository root folder with this command `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` and kept git bash opened all the time.